# curl_multi_exec() works with 7 calls, but I've got over 1000 calls to get through

Tags: php, php-curl, etsy

This is my first time using `curl_multi_init()` so I'm probably misunderstanding something. Learning to use it properly is more important to me than solving my problem because this particular function will solve a lot of my problems in future.

This particular call is for uploading Etsy photos. Etsy documentation for this call [here](https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/reference/#operation/uploadListingImage).

It works fine in Postman. The code snippet Postman generates for "PHP - cURL" works fine. It keeps working fine even after my edits to it.

Trouble is, I've got well over a thousand high resolution images to upload, so running the entire snippet from start to finish, then looping it a thousand times will time out no matter how generous my php.ini settings.

So, line by line I merged the existing code with a synchronous snippet and, I must have done something wrong. This example is almost exactly the live code. I've just deleted/simplified irrelevant things and redacted personal information. (Hopefully I didn't delete/simplify the bug.):

### Edit

This code works when limited to 7 calls. This is a very recent discovery, but absolutely critical to solving the question overall.

```
<?php
include_once 'databaseStuff.php';
include_once 'EtsyTokenStuff.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT product, listing_id, alt_text, dataStuff;");
$multiCurl = [];
$multiResult = [];
$multiHandle = curl_multi_init();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        for($image = 1; $image <=2; $image++){
            $multiCurl[$row['product'] . "_" . $image] = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($multiCurl[$row['product'] . "_" . $image], 
                array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/$myShopNumber/listings/" . $row['listing_id'] . "/images",
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                        "image" => new CURLFILE(
                            [
                                1 => "img/imagePathStuff/" . $row['product'] . ".jpg",
                                2 => "img/differentImagePathStuff/" . $row['product'] . ".jpg"
                            ][$image]
                        ),
                        // "listing_image_id" =>,
                        "rank" => $image,
                        "overwrite" => true,
                        // "is_watermarked" =>,
                        "alt_text" => $row['alt_text']
                    ),
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        "x-api-key: $myAPIKey",
                        "authorization: Bearer {$etsyAccessToken}"
                    ),
                )
            );
            curl_multi_add_handle($multiHandle, $multiCurl[$row['product'] . "_" . $image]);
        }
    }
    $index = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $index);
    } while($index > 0);
    foreach($multiCurl as $k => $curlHandle){
        $multiResult[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($curlHandle);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($multiHandle, $curlHandle);
    }
    curl_multi_close($multiHandle);
}
```

Once it starts working I'll probably block it out into functions, but I prefer to edit broken code in this format and add the function calls later.

### Newer Insights

Having never worked with these functions before, I'm not sure how they're supposed to behave but the behaviour I've noticed:

- If I limit the number of images uploaded to 7, everything works as intended. But if I run this code, no limit, even the first 7 images won't connect with the server. When I limit to 8 or higher, I hit an internal service error, but I suspect that might be an issue with my sloppy code. I need to look over it a few more times to see why it always crashes at the exact same point.
- No, it wasn't sloppy code. Commenting out `curl_multi_exec` removes the error. Commenting out everything below except `curl_multi_exec` and its loop does not remove the error. Max calls seems to be at 7, no matter which code snippet I borrow and replace. I can't even cause it to reduce to 6 with deliberately sloppy snippets. It's always 7.
- Opening php.ini and changing `memory_limit = 256M` to `memory_limit = 512M` not only fails to fix the problem, but makes the problem worse. Sending 7 results in an Internal Service Error. This was tested in the live environment, so I quickly reverted back to `memory_limit = 256M`. All damage caused was instantly repaired. I won't be testing that much further if I don't have to.

### Older insights

- The number of loops for the do-while loop varies from hundreds of thousands to millions while trying to upload 4 images. I suspect this is the correct number of loops, since everything else seems to work when it behaves this way. So now I know.
- This exact code has an Etsy specific problem. Ignore this if you aren't developing code for Etsy's API, but Etsy doesn't like it when you upload two photos to the same listing at the same time. Photos to different listings at the same time, however, is okay. So a loop that covers a single listing will not work.
- Following the advice of @Kazz, `while (false !== ($info = curl_multi_info_read($multiHandle))) { print_r($info); }` returns `Array ( [msg] => 1 [result] => 7 [handle] => Resource id #1009 )` for each item (with +1 to each Resource id for each result following). `7` corresponds with the error `"CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT"`.

### Earlier insights

- Although almost every change seems inconsequential, changing the URL to `https://google.com` causes everything to time out. Therefore, my code at least has access to the internet.
- Visiting the correct url in browser gives an authentication error, as I'd expect.
- All of the code executes, start to finish, no fatal errors.
- The do-while loop executes once then loops once more. (Maybe it's supposed to or maybe it's supposed to loop once per photo. Couldn't get that clarified anywhere.)
- It's supposed to update photos. Unfortunately the first test was on very minor edits, but trying again including a deliberately wrong photo I at least know that that particular photo didn't update, so probably none of them updated.
- `curl_multi_getcontent($curlHandle)` always returns an empty string
- `curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $index)` always returns 0 (previous claim that it was 1002 was incorrect. 1002 was actually the value of the second argument `$index` after running the function.)
- This particular call normally has very detailed responses for 201 and at least returns the error for 400, 401, 403, 404, 409, and 500, but I don't think my code is even going far enough to make the call. I haven't even figured out how to get the response codes at all.
- For a script that transfers well over one thousand high resolution images from my server to Etsy's server, it certainly executes very fast.
- The `$multiHandle` seems to work as intended. At the very least, a `var_dump($multiHandle)` reveals all the correct file names in there.

Here is a list of diagnostic functions I've tried and their outputs, again thanks to @Kazz for the functions.

- `while (false !== ($info = curl_multi_info_read($multiHandle))) { print_r($info); }` returns `Array ( [msg] => 1 [result] => 7 [handle] => Resource id #1009 )` for each item (with +1 to each Resource id for each result following)
- `print_r(dns_get_record('openapi.etsy.com', DNS_A));` returns  `Array ( [0] => Array ( [host] => e8520.b.akamaiedge.net [class] => IN [ttl] => 0 [type] => A [ip] => 104.127.77.191 ) )`
- `var_dump(exec('ping -c 3 openapi.etsy.com'));` returns `string(0) ""`
- `exec('ping -c 3 openapi.etsy.com', $output); var_dump($output);` returns `array(0) { }`
- `exec('ping -n 3 openapi.etsy.com', $output); var_dump($output);` returns `array(0) { }`
- [this whole thing](https://pastebin.com/cG2Rx2YX) returns "TCP/IP Connection
  OK. Attempting to connect to '104.127.77.191' on port '80'...OK. Sending HTTP GET request...OK. Reading response: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Server: AkamaiGHost Content-Length: 0 Location: openapi.etsy.com Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 02:34:15 GMT Connection: close Closing socket...OK."

It wouldn't surprise me if it's a minor typo causing this. What is it?

Comment: Is your title backwards? `curl` is synchronous, `curl_multi` is asynchronous (multiple requests run concurrently).

Comment: @Barmar maybe that's my problem? Running a curl script that sends and receives, then looping that script is about as asynchronous as it gets. Maybe I need a different pair of words entirely. I appreciate your help in improving my title. What would you suggest?

Comment: @Barmar new title. Did I just make it better or worse?

Comment: You made it's better :)

Comment: @Barmar thanks. It still feels too generic for a good Stack Overflow title. If you think of a better one let me know. I'll stick with this until I think of something better.

Comment: you should use regular `CURLOPT_POST => 1` instead `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'`, the 1002 error code is not listed anywhere, are you sure its result of `curl_multi_exec` and not something else ? like some code before this one ?

Comment: @Kazz Good catch. 1002 was the new value of the second argument, not the output. The output was "0" both times. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Kazz, I've updated the question. Thanks again. The fact that the community is still finding errors in my work gives me hope that an answer will be found.

Comment: @Kazz, I've tried your suggestion, `CURLOPT_POST => 1` instead of `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'`, but there is no change at all in the code's behaviour. Perhaps those are both valid ways of writing the same thing?

Comment: No they are not the same thing, `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` just and only just overwrite the text of request method, handlig of the curl object persist the same. In some cases, it doesn't matter, could be your case.  `CURLFILE` should be `CURLFile`. The return code 0 means CURLM_OK, so its fine. Also the script should execute fast unless internet connectivity bottleneck it, but if it's super fast then i would check presence of the images (if the path to them is correct like file_exist). If you want to check http responce code do it like: `curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);`

Comment: Empty result from `curl_multi_getcontent` doesn't necessary means an error, could be just empty response body, depends on the API implementation. In case you would want to see whole response with headers curl option: `CURLOPT_HEADER => 1` would do that, then `curl_multi_getcontent` would contain also the response headers.

Comment: @Kazz `curl_getinfo($curlHandle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);` returns "0". Thanks a bunch for that function anyway. I didn't even know that one.

Anyway, to make matters even more confusing, this last time I executed, the do-while loop executed 320 times.

I hit refresh, it executed twice. (The first time, and the while repeat).

Edit: I tried running it in different parts of the code. Always returns "0" no matter when I call it.

Comment: @Kazz adding `CURLOPT_HEADER => 1` results in exactly the same output as before. Just empty strings

Comment: even no headers ? damn that is concerning, try looking at individual return codes like: `while (false !== ($info = curl_multi_info_read($multiHandle))) { print_r($info); }` "mgs" will be always 1, "result" is the result of `curl_exec` for individual handle, which will lead you to the problem, "handle" will be resource, you can associate that to the value of `$multiCurl` array so you know which one was it

Comment: @Kazz `while (false !== ($info = curl_multi_info_read($multiHandle))) { print_r($info); }` didn't output anything. I put some extra text echos in there to test if the while loop was executing at all, and it isn't.

Comment: have you called that loop before `curl_multi_close` and `curl_multi_remove_handle` ?

Comment: @Kazz ah, whoops. You're instructions weren't sufficiently idiot proof. Okay, ran it again, each loop outputs `Array ( [msg] => 1 [result] => 7 [handle] => Resource id #1009 )` Result is always 7. I'm googling what that means now. Whatever it means, "7" feels like it's on the cusp of a breakthrough. `"CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT"` That's something! At least I know the problem now. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252010/discussion-between-jonathon-philip-chambers-and-kazz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the first answer I posted improved things from 0 to 7, but now things are improved from 7 to... 90ish? I don't think it consistently fails on the same number, and I'm not investigating further because only the first 10 calls per second are received by the server anyway.

The second improvement came from updating PHP from version 7 to version 7.4.

So, limiting `curl_multi_exec` to 10 calls, I can now loop out all the calls until it eventually hits a 503 error.

Luckily, @Booboo's solution fixed it.

So, in summary, the correct solutions are:

- Limit the number of calls manually
- Update PHP to at least 7.4. (More recent versions are unavailable for me to test, but more recent may be better.)
- Use @Booboo's snippet to fix 503 errors. (Give it an upvote if you use it. It's only fair.)

Comment: Don't forget that updating PHP may require you to rewrite your settings in php.ini. Forgetting that one did me quite a bit of damage

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bit of a guess, but if your problem is that your are timing out, then it seems that the following loop you coded may be the problem:

```PHP
    $index = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $index);
    } while($index > 0);
```

You are making repeated calls to `curl_multi_exec`, which is burning up CPU all the while you are waiting for all of your uploads to complete. You should instead only periodically be checking the status of your uploads and going into a wait state in between. This should reduce your total CPU time:

```PHP
    while (TRUE) {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $activeCount);
        if ($status == CURLM_OK && $activeCount) {
            // Wait some time before checking again:
            curl_multi_select($multiHandle, $timeout=1.0);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I commented out the code block above and added in its place the code block below, copy/pasted exactly as you wrote it without alteration.

Unfortunately, the code's behaviour, as far as I can tell, remains unchanged.

Are there any more diagnostic functions I can throw at this, just to work out what is even happening? I just wish I had more error messages to read.

Comment: A bit more digging, throwing in some echos, I can tell you the while loop breaks on the second cycle, executing `curl_multi_select` once and only once.

Is once the intended number of times? Sorry, still learning about these functions.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to hire someone to virtual machine solve this for me? Fixing the issue is worth a few dollars, but teaching me how to use this function correctly would be worth far more!

Comment: I just realized that I had the wrong variable name in my call to `curl_multi_select`. So if you copied "without alteration", that would be a problem. I have gone over your code again carefully (with more care than I took to write my call to `curl_multi_select`) and I do not see anything that looks like a typo.

Comment: so even the obviously broken code works the same as the currently broken code. That's depressing. I fixed it as you specified. No improvement.

The issue seems to be related to the URL path. It's behaving as I'd expect if the internet was disconnected, yet changing the path to https://google.com radically alters the code behaviour. (It's still broken, but broken to the point of timing out rather than returning something.)

Comment: Good news and bad news. Good news is your code works if I only upload 4 images at a time. (Haven't tested for larger numbers yet, but well over 1000 doesn't work.)

Bad news is I've also got it working for the original code, before this change. Progress though.

Comment: My code was to prevent a possible CPU execution timeout, which is not an issue with your uploading only 4 images but might be an issue with your original code if you were able to upload 1000 images.

Comment: Yes, I'm keeping it commented out because I strongly suspect I'll be needing it back. I've written a loop limiter into the code, which only allows it to upload 7 images at once. There's an internal service error at 8 images, however. The 7 images execute pretty quickly, so I think the limitation of <8 probably has something to do with my sloppy coding. Especially since 7 succeeds EVERY time and 8 fails EVERY time. But your code will probably come in handy once I hit 500+. We'll see.

Comment: Suspicion confirmed. The code keeps randomly crashing at different points, but it seems to do it less with this change. So I gave this answer the bounty, as it correctly identified a bottleneck, two bottle necks behind the one I was struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

you're probably tripping a rate-limit or connection-limit or anti-ddos-firewall or whatever beyond 7 concurrent connections. keep it under 8, something like (untested)

```php
<?php
include_once 'databaseStuff.php';
include_once 'EtsyTokenStuff.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT product, listing_id, alt_text, dataStuff;");
$multiCurl = [];
$multiResult = [];
$multiHandle = curl_multi_init();
$unemployed_workers = array();
$employed_workers = array();
$curl_responses = array();
$max_workers = 7;
for($i = 0; $i < $max_workers; ++$i){
    $unemployed_workers[] = curl_init();
}
$work = function()use(&$unemployed_workers, &$employed_workers, &$multiHandle, &$curl_responses){
    if(empty($employed_workers)){
        // nobody working, nothing to do..
        return;
    }
    for(;;){
        do{
            $err = curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $running);
        } while($err == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        if($err != CURLM_OK){
            throw new RuntimeException("curl_multi_exec error {$err}: ". curl_multi_strerror($err));
        }
        if(count($employed_workers) > $running){
            // at least 1 worker has finished, process it
            break;
        } else {
            // no workers have finished, wait for activity
            curl_multi_select($multiHandle, 1);
        }
    }
    while($msg = curl_multi_info_read($multiHandle)){
        if($msg['msg'] != CURLMSG_DONE){
            // unknown message, ignore?
            continue;
        }   
        $result = $msg['result'];
        if($result != CURLE_OK){
            throw new Exception("curl error {$result}: ". curl_error($msg['handle']));
        }
        $url = curl_getinfo($msg['handle'], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        $response = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);
        $curl_responses[$url] = $response;
        $key = array_search($done['handle'], $employed_workers, true);
        if($key === false){
            throw new LogicException("Could not find worker");
        }
        $unemployed_workers[] = $employed_workers[$key];
        unset($employed_workers[$key]);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($multiHandle, $done['handle']);
    }
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        for($image = 1; $image <=2; $image++){
            while(empty($unemployed_workers)){
                $work();
            }
            $worker = array_pop($unemployed_workers);
            $employed_workers[] = $worker;
            curl_setopt_array($worker, 
                array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://openapi.etsy.com/v3/application/shops/$myShopNumber/listings/" . $row['listing_id'] . "/images",
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_POST => true,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                        "image" => new CURLFILE(
                            [
                                1 => "img/imagePathStuff/" . $row['product'] . ".jpg",
                                2 => "img/differentImagePathStuff/" . $row['product'] . ".jpg"
                            ][$image] // what the fuck?
                        ),
                        // "listing_image_id" =>,
                        "rank" => $image,
                        "overwrite" => true,
                        // "is_watermarked" =>,
                        "alt_text" => $row['alt_text']
                    ),
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        "x-api-key: $myAPIKey",
                        "authorization: Bearer {$etsyAccessToken}"
                    ),
                )
            );
            curl_multi_add_handle($multiHandle, $worker]);
        }
    }
    while(!empty($employed_workers)){
        $work();
    }
    foreach($unemployed_workers as $worker){
        curl_close($worker);
    }
    curl_multi_close($multiHandle);
}
```

Comment: I managed to get it from 7 to around 90ish. I promised the bounty to someone else, but I'll write the full answer here if the bounty expires before they can get it. I didn't investigate what's causing the 90ish limit too closely because the end point is limited to 10 calls per second. It seems I've got a very different coding style to you, but I was able to limit `curl_multi_exec` to 10 using my own methods. Turns out the whole process takes longer than 1 second, so I didn't need to do anything further. This wasn't helpful to me, but I won't downvote it. It might still be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best answer, but it meets the minimum requirements of "an answer" and I don't want to keep shifting back the goal posts.

The code runs fine 7 calls at a time. So with a few loops, I should be able to get a 7x improvement on the original code. (Will update if this doesn't work.)

Running with over 1000 calls at a time, `curl_multi_exec` behaves as if it never executed at all.

Running with exactly 8 calls, I hit an Internal Service error `double free or corruption (out)` according to the CGI Error Log.

The above will produce more times if I refresh the page but I only seemed to get this error once: `php: malloc.c:3722: _int_malloc: Assertion '(unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb)' failed.`  (The first ' was actually a `, but that causes a formatting error on this site, so I changed it.)

Although only appearing once, it did appear while I was testing, so I'm certain it's relevant.

It seems I've found a gap between "well behaving success" and "well behaving failure", but I'm not brave enough to guess why the gap exists or speculate whether or not someone will patch it out.

I hope someone can explain to me why it only works for 7 and not 8. (Maybe it has something to do with php.ini, or CURLOPT.) I've updated the title accordingly to attract someone who might know the answer. But "only run it for 7 calls" is a valid answer to the question of how to get it working at all.

Comment: seems like you found internal bug of php or libcurl, both errors are at the C level, you should try different versions of php: v < 7.3.0, 7.3.0 <= v < 8.0.0, v >= 8.0.0, in case even the latest version behave the same you should report it as a bug to bugtracker

Comment: @Kazz, okay, tomorrow I will Google what bugtracker even is. (I told you I was new to this) I've been deliberately avoiding updating PHP because last time I did, some of the default ini values changed, crashing my code. But I might try upgrading it for a few seconds before reverting back. See if that helps. If it does... I'll spend the next few days wishing I practised Test Driven Development, because that would have been so useful for times like this.

Comment: btw kind of annoys me that OP's code is void of error-checking, there's no checking against CURLE_OK/CURLM_OK/curl_errno

Comment: @hanshenrik I think you mean to say, "Have you considered the benefits of adding error-checking to your code? There's an opportunity to check against CURLE_OK, CURLM_OK, and curl_errno. The benefits are described in this linked article!" It's okay, I can find the article myself. Typos happen. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i simply used [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php) with a loop to get around this.

Here is a sample to get the idea :

```
$my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
$nb_batch = 5;
$array_chunk = array_chunk($my_array, $nb_batch, true);
foreach( $array_chunk as $my_array ) {
    foreach( $my_array as $key => $value ) {
        // do all the curl_multi_exec stuff here
    }
}
```

With this code :

- You store everything you need for your cUrl calls in `$my_array`.
- Then you split this array into chunks.
- Then you loop through chunks array.
- And then you loop throught each chunks and execute your multi cUrl
  calls.